# Как сделать такой фильтр, а потом объединить результат?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[https://codepen.io/GunAlv/pen/OJMyVXp?**cf_chl_jschl_tk**=ba9737b6ba5959a6ee6d4dfcc0f360c7ac975b6b-1591606742-0-AQnO6WO_hTDvBCfhMtMHi7I6c6ON0IznbSflg7s6LPklbKVPBD5HPAkYXOgma6aJEOvO15hG0W_2-TaNBUSmLQQ1hTJcE87r0tYVR6L6ghlZyYEPN6BTh8VSXsCWpFfv8i4HLpan5aNKqw-Cjc3Qp9aB-vdG1vL_6LXcxvo9qiYknomZOn4jca60dytqBoxGTK2cO6bhLdNbmB1idT5ZkverM4YJIDXGpUJw0YCgDbB9OyHjmkDhUKgGAzrs_s9aVbyiE6WA7ZE8yIYdms7AdHpGL1D7LXUSYaG87GFXXaMw1VHvf5n_mC3H-2LESCAMl1tusa9WRomK-UHi3e3xfyI](https://codepen.io/GunAlv/pen/OJMyVXp?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=ba9737b6ba5959a6ee6d4dfcc0f360c7ac975b6b-1591606742-0-AQnO6WO_hTDvBCfhMtMHi7I6c6ON0IznbSflg7s6LPklbKVPBD5HPAkYXOgma6aJEOvO15hG0W_2-TaNBUSmLQQ1hTJcE87r0tYVR6L6ghlZyYEPN6BTh8VSXsCWpFfv8i4HLpan5aNKqw-Cjc3Qp9aB-vdG1vL_6LXcxvo9qiYknomZOn4jca60dytqBoxGTK2cO6bhLdNbmB1idT5ZkverM4YJIDXGpUJw0YCgDbB9OyHjmkDhUKgGAzrs_s9aVbyiE6WA7ZE8yIYdms7AdHpGL1D7LXUSYaG87GFXXaMw1VHvf5n_mC3H-2LESCAMl1tusa9WRomK-UHi3e3xfyI)

```
<div class="gas-filter">
        <div class="gas-filter__item">
            <p class="gas-filter__item-label">
                Вид топлива:
            </p>
            <div class="gas-filter__items">
                <input data-gas-checkbox-type type="checkbox" class="gas-filter__checkbox visually-hidden" id="type-all" checked>
                <label class="gas-filter__checkbox-label" for="type-all">Все</label>
                <input data-gas-checkbox-type type="checkbox" class="gas-filter__checkbox visually-hidden" id="type-ai-92">
                <label class="gas-filter__checkbox-label" for="type-ai-92">АИ 92</label>
                <input data-gas-checkbox-type type="checkbox" class="gas-filter__checkbox visually-hidden" id="type-ai-95">
                <label class="gas-filter__checkbox-label" for="type-ai-95">АИ 95</label>
                <input data-gas-checkbox-type type="checkbox" class="gas-filter__checkbox visually-hidden" id="type-dt">
                <label class="gas-filter__checkbox-label" for="type-dt">ДТ</label>
                <input data-gas-checkbox-type type="checkbox" class="gas-filter__checkbox visually-hidden" id="type-kpg">
                <label class="gas-filter__checkbox-label" for="type-kpg">КПГ</label>
                <input data-gas-checkbox-type type="checkbox" class="gas-filter__checkbox visually-hidden" id="type-spg">
                <label class="gas-filter__checkbox-label" for="type-spg">СПГ</label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="gas-filter__item">
            <p class="gas-filter__item-label">
                Объекты:
            </p>
            <div class="gas-filter__items">
                <input data-gas-checkbox-object type="checkbox" class="gas-filter__checkbox visually-hidden" id="objects-all" checked>
                <label class="gas-filter__checkbox-label" for="objects-all">Все</label>
                <input data-gas-checkbox-object type="checkbox" class="gas-filter__checkbox visually-hidden" id="objects-agzs">
                <label class="gas-filter__checkbox-label" for="objects-agzs">АГЗС</label>
                <input data-gas-checkbox-object type="checkbox" class="gas-filter__checkbox visually-hidden" id="objects-mazk">
                <label class="gas-filter__checkbox-label" for="objects-mazk">МАЗК</label>
                <input data-gas-checkbox-object type="checkbox" class="gas-filter__checkbox visually-hidden" id="objects-gns">
                <label class="gas-filter__checkbox-label" for="objects-gns">ГНС</label>
                <input data-gas-checkbox-object type="checkbox" class="gas-filter__checkbox visually-hidden" id="objects-shop">
                <label class="gas-filter__checkbox-label" for="objects-shop">Магазин</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



<div class="place-list"> 
  <div class="place" data-type="[type-ai-92, type-kpg ]" data-object="objects-shop">Магазин</div>

  <div class="place" data-type="[type-kpg]" data-object="objects-mazk">МАЗК</div>

  <div class="place" data-type="[type-kpg, type-dt, type-ai-95, type-ai-92]" data-object="objects-agzs">АГЗС</div>

  <div class="place" data-type="[type-kpg, type-ai-95, type-ai-92]" data-object="objects-gns">ГНС</div>

  <div class="place" data-type="[type-dt, type-ai-95]" data-object="objects-gns">ГНС</div>

  <div class="place" data-type="[type-ai-92, type-kpg, type-dt]" data-object="objects-shop">Магазин</div>

  <div class="place" data-type="[type-dt, type-ai-92]" data-object="objects-agzs">АГЗС</div>

  <div class="place" data-type="[type-kpg, type-dt, type-ai-95, type-ai-92]" data-object="objects-mazk">МАЗК
  </div>

  <div class="place" data-type="[type-dt]" data-object="objects-mazk">МАЗК</div>

  <div class="place" data-type="[type-kpg, type-dt]" data-object="objects-shop">Магазин</div>

  <div class="place" data-type="[type-spg]" data-object="objects-shop">Магазин</div>
</div>
```

Суть в том, что у одного места может быть несколько видов топлива, они прописаны в data-type класса place.
Примитивную фильтрацию по объектам (data-object) я реализовать могу, но сложность представляет data-type с его массивом топлива, а потом — объединение результатов обоих фильтров и отображение нужного места